# Audio no se actualiza

Tags: javascript, audio

queria gestionar la siguiente pregunta, al momento de crear el audio me lo crea bien, le doy reproducir y se reproduce bien, pero al momento de crear uno nuevo lo crea pero al reproducir reproduce el audio anterior y tengo que darle play otra vez para que reproduzca el nuevo, Alguno puede tener idea de que puede ser, Es un audio generado con Tts Ibm Watson PORFAVOR AYUDA

```js
function getData(text,audio){
    document.getElementById('audio').setAttribute("src","");
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    console.log(text);
    $.post("{{route ('WatsonTts.php')}}",{"text":text},
    function(respuesta){alert(respuesta);});
    // var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.src = '/horafacil-one-5.5.git/storage/grabaciones/mensaje.wav?audio=' + Math.random();
    // document.body.innerHTML += "<div><audio id='audio' preload='none' controls><source type='audio/wav' src='/horafacil-one-5.5.git/storage/grabaciones/mensaje.wav'></audio></button></div>";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Mensaje</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                <input id="text" type="text" name="text">
                                <button type="button" onclick="getData()"> Play </button>                
                            </div>
                            <audio id="audio" controls>
                                {{-- /horafacil-one-5.5.git/storage/grabaciones/mensaje.wav --}}
                            </audio>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: necesitamos mas que solo esto ya que no nos explicas como son tus audios para que es el $.post y en todos mandas a llamar a `mensaje.wav`

Comment: El post es para ejecutar IBM WATSON TTS
se manda un texto y este lo transforma a audio, y todos se llaman mensaje.wav porque la idea es que al momento de crearlo reemplace el anterior, esto lo realiza pero al momento de reproducir se queda el antiguo y es necesario darle 2 veces play para que reproduzca el nuevo

Comment: pero no usas la repuesta por post solo agregas un audio random con  `?audio=' + Math.random()` asi que sigo sin entender :v podrias colocar mas codigo!

Comment: _«y todos se llaman mensaje.wav porque la idea es que al momento de crearlo reemplace el anterior»..._ ¿Y entonces el random qué sentido tiene? Si siempre se llama `mensaje.wav` y está en la misma carpeta (en el servidor), ni siquiera tendrías que cambiar el `src` como haces, se supone que la llamada al servidor crea el nuevo archivo y lo guarda bajo `mensaje.wav` ¿no?